# java erasures of derived generic type

Tags: java, generics, derived-class, type-erasure, overriding

I'm coming in with a problem I'm getting trying to implement a "two-level" casting.

Below is the simplified code to show what I am trying to do :

```
public class Array2D<T>
{
    private T[][] _array;
    ....
    public T get( int x , int y )
    ....
    public void set( T o , int x , int y )
}
```

Until there, no problem.

I'm trying to extend this class such as I could encapsulate the use of SoftReferences in the getter and setter :

```
public class Array2DSoftRefs<T> extends Array2D<SoftReference<T>>
{
    public T get( int x , int y )
    {
        return super.get(x,y).get(); // get the array element, then the SoftReference contents
    }
    ....
    public void set( T o , int x , int y )
    {
        super.set( new SoftReference<T>(o) ,x,y); // generate the SoftReference on-the-fly
    }
```

}

Indeed, I'm kicked off because the compiler / syntax analyzer skips the generics erasures, then the `@Override` annotation cannot help me (captain obvious).

I can't figure out how to return a `T` type from the `SoftReference<T>` template.

I tried to put in two generics `T` and `U` for `SoftReference<T>`, but without succeeding.

Comment: The term _template_ is not used in Java.  The terms _generics_ and _type parameters_ are used in stead.

Comment: What is the exact compiler error message?

Comment: @jahroy Thanks for the edit and the word, I'm still having reminiscences of my C++ background.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with `Array2DSoftRef.get` is that you can't override a method and make its return type less specific (e.g. `SoftReference<T>` -> `T`).

The problem with `Array2DSoftRef.set` is that you can't override a method if it has different parameters (e.g. `T` instead of `SoftReference<T>`) but you also can't overload it if it will have the same parameters after [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

I would recommend you use composition instead of inheritance here:

```
public class Array2DSoftRefs<T> {

    private final Array2D<SoftReference<T>> inner = ...;

    public T get( int x , int y ) {
        return inner.get(x,y).get();
    }

    public void set( T o , int x , int y ) {
        inner.set(new SoftReference<T>(o), x, y);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you'll have to rename your `get` and `set` in `Array2DSoftRefs` to avoid the name clash - but remember the parent `get` and `set` will still be publicly exposed this way.

Comment: +1. OP: Remember that by making `Array2DSoftRefs<T>` extend `Array2D<SoftReference<T>>` you are stating that the former can be used anywhere the latter is used (the Liskov Substitution Principle)--which isn't very useful in your case, since you're trying to make the SoftReference logic invisible to the user. If you want to indicate that an `Array2DSoftRefs<T>` could substitute for any `Array2D<T>`, create an interface with all the `Array2D` methods and have both classes extend it.

Comment: OK thanks ! It seems the only solution is yours : I will create a common interface IArray2D to ensure the erasures of these classes and make them the same erasure.